# Purpose of using permitAll() in PreAuthorize annotation in Spring Security

Tags: java, security, spring-security, annotations, spring-annotations

Being new to spring security framework, I wanted to know why do we use `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")` with methods ? The documentation says that permitAll always evaluates to true. (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

Also, I have the below code change. The developer makes change from permitAll() to specific permission check.What is the implication here? Since I am not too sure about how permitAll() works, I am not able to judge the logic behind the code change. It seems to me that the developer adds specific permission checks and he passes null as the authentication object. Could someone explain what is the impact of explicitly passing null as the authentication object? Is it that users who are not authenticated will have access if they have this specific - 'LUONTI' permission on the target object - 'opetussuunnitelma' ?

```
-    @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
+    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(null, 'opetussuunnitelma', 'LUONTI')")
     OpetussuunnitelmaDto addOpetussuunnitelma(OpetussuunnitelmaDto opetussuunnitelmaDto);
```

Thanks. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`permitAll()` does exactly what it says. It allows (permits) any user's (all) session to be authorized to execute that method.

The way spring manages its authentication and authorization means that anyone accessing your site is provided with a session. This session can be anonymous, or authenticated (user's provided some kind of credential and the system has accepted it). Alternatives to `permitAll` (`hasPermission()` for example) will usually check the user's authentication to ensure they have some role or group assigned to them before allowing the annotated class/method to be invoked.

If `permitAll()` is used, it means to explicitly allow any session, anonymous or authenticated, to access the annotated method.

The code change the other developer has made has restricted the given method to something custom. Take a look at this [Spring - Expression-Based Access Control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

Comment: If permitAll() allowes everything, then it is as good as not having any annotation check. So why should anyone use it in the first place?

Comment: Also, is my interpretation w.r.t the usage of null in the above code correct?

Comment: I'm not sure why your code had it there to begin with, but it _may_ actually be different than no annotation. Spring cascades the `@PreAuthorize` annotations because they're applicable to classes too. If a `@PreAuthorize` annotation is on the class, and then nothing is on the method, the method inherits the classes `@PreAuthorize`. 

He could have also done it with the intent of being explicit ("Any user can use potentially access this, don't return any sensitive information")

Comment: May be the default mode is not "permitAll" and that's why you have to explicitly mention it using the annotation. I am looking for some concrete reasoning.

Comment: Without being able to see your entire spring configuration it will be near impossible to give you concrete reasoning for it being there. 

The usage of null means that the implementation of `PermissionEvaluator` being used for your `hasPermission()` calls doesn't care about any `Authentication` objects (maybe it's pulling it from session each time instead). Unfortunately it's really hard to give you explicit reasoning without seeing more than just this method signature.

Comment: Here's the link to the code that I am trying to understand. https://github.com/Opetushallitus/eperusteet-ylops/commit/1ae8e39c2cb27739603b052a59fb7ce9e375b114

Comment: looks like you are right, the hasPermission method in the permissionEvaluator is returning true all the time regardless of authentication. But what would be the implication if the developer does not pass null ? I am just thinking whether the usage of null was unnecessary or not

Comment: I went through the code, and besides just being explicit about permissions (which is a good reason) I can't find a concrete, functional reason behind it.
If you passed an actual Authentication into the method, then the PermissionEvaluator implemented can investigate the provided Authentication to determine whether it's authorized to access the method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81574/discussion-between-zack-and-dave-lugg).

Comment: I sometimes use `permitAll` on controller interfaces to enforce proxy object to be created.

Answer (score 13):

I feel like nobody really gave you what you really wanted, which is a use case for "permitAll()".

It can be used when you restrict your whole class or application with a certain permission, for example :
`@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")`

Here, only the clients identified as what you defined to be a user can have access to the methods of your class.

But at some point in your controller you want a certain method to be permissionless, so you'll add `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")` to your method so that it override the global permission.

People will do this because it's safer to first secure everything with the highest permission lock and then poke holes in the net (e.g, the application/class is locked to ADMIN but most methods are then authorized to USER) than the other way around. Because if everything is unlocked by default, the day you forget to lock a controller you could have security problems.